# Cannot Read New Page HTML Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to get scraped data from a results page, after I have entered search variables on the previous page. I cannot get the .doc HTML to reflect the new page's html, (well not consistently, it reads correctly in 5-10% of cases). I have looked at other solutions for this problem and the majority come down to not waiting for the new page html to appear, but I have put 5,10 even twenty second waits in but that doesn't seem to do the trick. 
Any advice / pointers would be welcome

```
<code>Sub ParseInternet()

Dim post_code As String
Dim house_num As String
post_code = CStr(Sheet1.Cells(9, 2).Value)  'get search data from worksheet
house_num = CStr(Sheet1.Cells(9, 1).Value)
If post_code = "" Then
    MsgBox ("House Name /Number and postcode MUST be entered")
    Exit Sub
End If
Set site = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
Dim url As String
url = "http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/app/ppd"

site.Navigate url
While site.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

site.Visible = True
site.Document.getElementById("paon").Value = house_num
site.Document.getElementById("postcode").Value = post_code
Set my_classes = site.Document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary")
For Each my_class In my_classes
     my_class.Click
Next my_class   

While site.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
 Dim a As String
 Dim b As String
 b = "property by searching for"
 '''STILL PREVIOUS PAGE HTML IN .DOC
 Set HTMLLI = site.Document.getElementsByTagName("div")

 For xli = 0 To HTMLLI.Length - 1
    a = site.Document.getElementsByTagName("div")(xli).innerText
    If InStr(site.Document.getElementsByTagName("div")(xli).innerText, b) Then
        Sheet1.Cells(9, 4).Value = site.Document.getElementsByTagName("div")(xli).innerText
        Exit For
    End If

Next xli
site.Quit
Set site = Nothing
End Sub
</code>
```

Comment: Why not to scrape the data via XHR instead of IE automation?

Comment: Can you use XHR when you do not have a specific URL of the results page?

Comment: You can find XHR after you click "Show results" manually in browser, in Developer Tools, Network tab: the URL is http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/app/ppd/search, method POST, also there are Form Data parameters. Seems there is no need to make POST XHR, since the server responses to simple GET XHR by the URL like http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/app/ppd/search?paon=17&postcode=pl6, more of that the direct link to download csv data is http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/app/ppd/ppd_data.csv?limit=all&paon=17&postcode=pl6

Comment: The original question was more to do with what's wrong with the statement rather than how to get the end data, however,thanks for this. How do I send a SPARQL query